# Bootstrap popover is not working on iPad safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

I made a simple Bootstrap popover, I called popover() function (using jQuery). Everything seems to be ok but when I tested on iPad it is not working.

```
<a href="#" title="Description" 
data-trigger="focus" 
data-container="body" 
data-toggle="popover" 
data-placement="top" 
data-content="This is a test for iPad">Click here to see description</a>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/masiht/et26me1d/13/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a trouble finding the solution, here is the fixed code, I hope it will work for someone one day:

I think (data-trigger="focus") is the part that made problem. It will work also on iPad by removing this attribute.

```
<a data-container="body" 
data-toggle="popover" 
data-placement="top" 
data-content="This is a test for iPad" data-original-title="" title="Description">This works</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/masiht/et26me1d/15/

Comment: If you don't need it to close the popover when clicking outside the element then Yes removing  "data-trigger="focus"" will do the job otherwise you need to add `tabindex="0"` and  `role="button"` to make it work on Safari.

Answer (score 31):

Sometimes you need it to work with `data-trigger="focus"` and for those instances to be platform independent you should follow this example:

```
<a tabindex="0" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" 
      data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover"
      data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
  Dismissible popover
</a>
```

Key is to make sure you use an `<a>` tag and also have `tabindex="0"` and the `role` attribute set.

It took me a while to find this in [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click). Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This was the answer I was searching for because Safari requires that the tag is an anchor <a> but other browsers support other element tags.

Comment: tabindex="0" role="button" just add this to your anchor tag

Answer (score 2):

I have tried everything for iOS compatibility, this below is the only function I have found which reliably works in iOS browsers.

HTML:-

```
<a tabindex="0" class="popupover" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus" title="popover title" data-content="popover text here">Click Here</a>
```

JS:-

```
$('.popupover').popover();
jQuery("body").on("click touchstart", '.popupover', function() {
   $(this).popover("show");
        $('.popupover').not(this).popover("hide"); // hide other popovers
        return false;
    });
jQuery("body").on("click touchstart", function() {
    $('.popupover').popover("hide"); // hide all popovers when 
    clicked on body
});
```

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
&lt;a href="javascript:void(0)" class="popupover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="click" title="Popover" data-content="something here"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
```

JS:

```
$('.popupover').popover();
jQuery("body").on("click touchstart", '.popupover', function() {
$(this).popover("show");
    $('.popupover').not(this).popover("hide"); // hide other popovers
    return false;
});
jQuery("body").on("click touchstart", function() {
    $('.popupover').popover("hide"); // hide all popovers when clicked on body
});
```